# Node.js kafka-node partitioner type usage

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to insert data into kafka topic through node js using kafka-node.

Data does not get inserted if I try to use partitionerType. Code works if I remove PartitionerType (i.e. without using options) but in that case all data goes to only one partition.

Could you please help me in resolving the issue. Thanks in advance.

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Producer = kafka.Producer,
    KeyedMessage = kafka.KeyedMessage,
    client = new kafka.Client("zookeeper-host:2181","node-id"),
    options = {
    requireAcks: 1,
    ackTimeoutMs: 100,
    partitionerType: 3
        },
    producer = new Producer(client, options);
    //producer = new Producer(client);  -- This works

    var km = new KeyedMessage('key1', 'message6'),
    kn = new KeyedMessage('key2', 'message5'),
    kv = new KeyedMessage('key3', 'message4'),
    kx = new KeyedMessage('key4', 'message3'),
    ky = new KeyedMessage('key5', 'message2'),
    kz = new KeyedMessage('key6', 'message1'),
    payloads = [
        { topic: 'test-topic3', messages: [km,kn,kv,kx,ky,kz] }
    ];
    console.log("Ready to send data");
    producer.on('ready', function () {
    producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    });

console.log("DATA SENT");
```

Many Thanks

Pari

Answer (score 0):

Above code is working fine with HighLevelConsumer.

Thanks
Pari

Answer (score 0):

Use refreshMetadata method...

In my case, it works.

Refer to the following links...

https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/436

`client.refreshMetadata([topic1, topic2], callback)`